# NativeScript Application breaks while moving position on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have added google maps in my mobile application using Nativescript google maps plugin. Here is my html

```
<MapView #mapView [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom" [minZoom]="minZoom" [maxZoom]="maxZoom" [bearing]="bearing" [tilt]="tilt" i-padding="50,50,50,50" [padding]="padding" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" (markerInfoWindowTapped)="onMarkerWindowTapped($event)" (cameraChanged)="onCameraChanged($event)" row="1" col="0" colspan="2"> </MapView>
```

I have a dropdown which has a dropdown showing multiple markers on the map. I wanted to change the camera position when i change the value in dropdown. Here is how i handle dropdown change event

```
onchange(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {

let event = this.events.filter(event => event._id === this.itemSource.getValue(args.newIndex));

console.dir(event);
//this.latitude =  event[0].locationInfo.coordinates[0];
//this.longitude = event[0].locationInfo.coordinates[1];
```

}

This code executes successfully if i uncomment last 2 lines and camera position is getting changed. However after camera position is changed, i get below unknown exception which i am unable to debug

```
System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err: at com.tns.NativeScriptUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(NativeScriptUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:55) System.err: at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068) System.err: at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063) System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.PendingIntent.send(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference System.err: at com.tns.ErrorReport.startPendingErrorActivity(ErrorReport.java:156) System.err: at com.tns.ErrorReport.startActivity(ErrorReport.java:133) System.err: ... 4 more System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err: at com.tns.NativeScriptUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(NativeScriptUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:55) System.err: at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068) System.err: at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063) System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.PendingIntent.send(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference System.err: at com.tns.ErrorReport.startPendingErrorActivity(ErrorReport.java:156) System.err: at com.tns.ErrorReport.startActivity(ErrorReport.java:133) System.err: ... 4 more
```

Can someone at least provide me hint on what might be causing the same? Please note that if i comment the lines for changing lat/long when i change my dropdown, everything works perfectly fine.